# How do I migrate my local postgresql database to azk?

Tags: postgresql, migration, azk

There's directions for migrating an existing MySQL database to an azk image here: http://images.azk.io/#/mysql?_k=yvigvq

How can I do the same for postgresql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just make a PR adding the instructions in the repository of the image:

https://github.com/azukiapp/docker-postgres/pull/3

see section: [Migrating an existing PostgreSQL Server](https://github.com/azukiapp/docker-postgres/tree/6232d0f484a508f35b378deb75cdeca5790a1176#migrating-an-existing-postgresql-server)

Answer (score 3):

There are basically three ways to restore a dump file to a database running inside `azk` (they also work with other DBs such as MySQL and MariaDB):

1- Using a local client (graphical tool or command line tool):

Before connecting to the database, you need to find out the database running port:

```
$ azk start postgres  # Ensures the database is running
$ azk status postgres
┌───┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┐
│   │ System   │ Instances │ Hostname/url │ Instances-Ports │ Provisioned │
├───┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ ↑ │ postgres │ 1         │ dev.azk.io   │ 1-data:32831    │ -           │
└───┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Now, we can connect to the database using the host `dev.azk.io` and the resulting port from the previous command (`32381`). The username, password and database name are defined in the `Azkfile`.

[image: Connecting to the DB]

2- Using `azk shell` and the database CLI:

Running the same steps described above to find out the database running port, you can run the following command:

```
$ azk shell postgres
$ psql --host dev.azk.io --port 32831 --username ${POSTGRES_USER} \
--password=${POSTGRES_PASS} --dbname=${POSTGRES_DB} < dbexport.sql
```

3 - Using autoload script from the database image:

Most of the official Docker Images for databases has an `entrypoint` script, which looks for files in the folder `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and run them when the database is initialized. Given that, you can simply mount your dump files (`.sql`) in that location, like described in the following `Azkfile`:

```js
systems({
 postgres: {
   image: { docker: "azukiapp/postgres" },
   mounts: {
     "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d": sync("./dumps"),
   }
 }
});
```

Starting the `postgres` system with the command `azk start postgres`, the dump files will be run automatically.

Obs: As you can see in the [Postgres' script](http://to.azk.io/1TwqHsY) and  in the [Mysql's](http://to.azk.io/1qkv5jV), the dump files can be plain text (`.sql`), compressed (`.sql.gz`) or even shell scripts (`.sh`).